# Strategy to select correct Aggregate root, so transaction won't span multiple aggregates

Tags: transactions, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm modeling Category/Menu domain context and decided to have 2 Aggregate roots for this context.

```
 public class MenuItem : Aggregate<Guid>
{
    public List<string> ImageUrls { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IList<ExtraProperty> Extras { get; set; }
    public ITranslationList<MenuItemTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}




 public class Category : Aggregate<Guid>
 {
    public ITranslationList<CategoryTranslation> Translations { get; set;}
     public SortedList<int,Guid> Children { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImageUrls { get; set; }

    internal Category() { }


}
```

In Category model, Children property is sorted list of child Category and MenuItems ids.

Now suppose I want to create category. I have a command for this purpose:

```
  public class CreateCategoryCommand:ICommand
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImageUrls { get; set; }
    public ITranslationList<CategoryTranslation> Translations  { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ParentSortIndex { get; set; }
  }
```

So what happens here is, I create category, if ParentId property is set, I get category with that id from repository, add record to Children sorted list and save parent category as well.

The problem is in this case transaction spans 2 aggregates (newly created aggregate and parent).

Because of this I have a feeling I modeled my aggregate boundaries incorrectly. On one hand I try to make aggregate as small as possible as suggested by Vaughn Vernon (that's why Category contains Id references, not actual objects), on the other hand transaction spans multiple aggregates, when saving one, which is design flaw IMHO.

What would be your strategy/suggestions/opinions for modeling this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Categories** are in a hierarchical structure. Is there any particular reason why you modeled them by adding a **Children** property that contains child category IDs?

If you turn the reference direction from child to parent by removing **Children** property and adding a **ParentID** property this will resolve your consistency boundary problem. Adding new **Categories** won't affect the parent.

You can add a methods **GetChildren(parentID)** or **GetChildrenIDs(parentID)** to a **CategoryRepository** to get the children or their IDs of a **Category** if they are needed.

Edit:

Having more information on the application and it's requirements is important in implementations. Different requirements cause for different invariants and will cause different consistency boundaries for **Aggregates**.

I'll give a example implementation for specific requirements. They are not complete as writing all the code with all cases will require a lot of text.

Let's ask couple of questions about the ordering of **Categories**.

- **Question 1:** How is the **ParentSortIndex** calculated from the **Command** sender so that it can be set to the **Command**?
- **Question 2:** If a **Category** doesn't have children, is it valid to receive a **Command** with **ParentSortIndex** = 10?
- **Question 3:** Is the value **ParentSortIndex** important or is the ordering of categories the only thing that matters?

Let's say that the ordering of **Categories** is the only thing that matters and how it's is implemented or the value of the **SortIndex** isn't important.

First let's introduce the concept of a **SortingIndex**. Now, let's think of an implementation of this concept. We can use float as the value of a **SortingIndex** instead of int (or double if we expect a lot of **Categories**). Floats have a nice property that you can (almost) always find one that fits between two other floats. For example if you have 1 and 2, 1.5 is between them, 1.2 is between 1 and 1.5 and so on.

Next lets add **CategoryRepository.GetSortingIndicesForChilren(parentId)** method. This method will get an object with properties for a **CategoryGuid and SortingIndex** for all children of a parent so that we can calculate a **SortingIndex** that is right next to the requested **Category**.

This will avoid having to load all children. Having special values returned from **Reposistories** is a nice technique. In the [DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), Eric Evans explains it and says that it's quite normal for **Repositories** to return such special objects that contains some info or data.

Next let's specify to which child we want to place the new child category instead of specifying a concrete index value. (We may wish to place it above of bellow the category, but I'll skip this case for simplicity. It can be resolved with a enum { placeAbove, placeBellow } that can be added to the **Command**)

```
public class SortingIndex : ValueObject {

  public static readonly MinValue = new SotringIndex(float.MinValue);
  public static readonly MidValue = new SotringIndex(float.MaxValue);
  public static readonly MaxValue = new SotringIndex(float.MaxValue);

  public float Value { get; private set; }

  public SortingIndex(float value) { .... }

  public SortingIndex GetBtween(SortingIndex other) { ... }

  public static operator > (OrderingPriority other) { .. }
  public static operator >= (OrderingPriority other) { .. }
  // other operators <=, ==, != etc.
}

public class Category : Aggregate<Guid> {
   public Guid ParentGuid { get; private set; }
   public SortingIndex SortingIndex { get; private set; }
   // constructor and other stuff......
}

public class CreateCategoryCommand : ICommand
{
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Guid? CategoryGuidToPlaceNextTo { get; set; }
    // other stuff...
}

public class CreateCategoryCommandHandler {

  public void Handle(CreateCategoryCommand cmd) {

    var sortingIndex = SortingIndex.MidValue;

    // start with mid value. If there aren't any children, this will be the 
       first. Later when we add other children we can calculate an index 
       before of after this one.

    if(cmd.ParentID != null && cmd.CategoryGuidToPlaceNextTo != null) {

          var childrenSortingIndices = CategoryRepository
                           .GetSortingIndicesForChilren(cmd.ParentID);

           sortingIndex = PlaceChildNextTo(
                            childrenSortingIndices,
                            cmd.CategoryGuidToPlaceNextTo);
     }

    var category = new Category(cmd.ID, cmd.ParentID, sortingIndex, ...);

    CategoryRepository.Save(category);
  }
}
```

In the situation described above, because there aren't any rules for having specific values for the indices, we can implement them in a way to avoid conflicts between children and having to mutate any state.

Having a collection with children will cause a state mutation on that collection.

Having integers causes high probability of collisions between indices and will cause recalculation of child indices. This will span multiple aggregates.

Adding new **Category** is simple as we only need to find an index that is after (or between two Categories) a specified category without having the need to modify a collection or other child categories.

If the above isn't true and there are rules for the values of the **SortingIndex** that means that there are additional invariants to be satisfied and will cause different consistency boundaries.

You can still implement this by having eventual consistency or having a [Saga](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) that will manage a distributed transaction between the Parent Category and the new Category. In this scenario you can't escape Eventual consistency and will have additional things to worry about.

Still if you think that having eventual consistency is a problem and you don't want to deal with the complexities, you can modify two aggregates in the same transaction if your application allows it. You can't do this in a distributes application.

Comment: Sure, but problem arises when I need to sort items inside category. In suggested case I need to load all children of parent category to change sort index, and that is real performance issue.